# Group dates by month and sort then descending using lodash and moment

Tags: javascript, momentjs, lodash

I have the following array containing a JSON object defined below

```
[
{
    "modDate": "2017-06-20"
},
{
    "modDate": "2017-10-24"
},
{
    "modDate": "2017-08-03"
}
]
```

and i want the result to be grouped in first place by month and then sorted by in descending order by month.

I have tried grouping it with this

```
grouped_items = _.groupBy(data, (b) ->
  moment(b.modDate).startOf('month').format('YYYY/MM')
```

but is am not getting the correct result.

Comment: just a typo, fixed

Answer (score 8):

If I understood you correctly, you want to create a grouped collection of the data by the month, and then sort the values descendingly by the day of month (as sorting by month in the values doesn't make sense).

If so, the following should work:

```js
const data = [{"modDate":"2017-06-20"},{"modDate":"2017-06-25"},{"modDate":"2017-10-24"},{"modDate":"2017-10-20"},{"modDate":"2017-08-03"}];

let grouped_items = _.groupBy(data, (b) =>
  moment(b.modDate).startOf('month').format('YYYY/MM'));

_.values(grouped_items)
  .forEach(arr => arr.sort((a, b) => moment(a.modDate).day() - moment(b.modDate).day()));

console.log(grouped_items);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is there any way to sort the key(the month) as well? :)